# Select rows from a table that has one column matching a combination of columns from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have Table1 and Table2.

Table1 has columnA and columnB and a bunch of others. Table2 has columnC and other columns.

I want to query out all rows from Table2 that satisfies: `columnC` follows this pattern: `{Table1_columnA}\_{blahblahblah}\_{Table1_columnB}`. Note that `columnC` can have other values like "123_456_789" which has two underscores but does not follow above pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t2.columnC LIKE '%' || t1.columnA || '\blahblahblah\' || t1.columnB || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select *
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on
       t2.columc = concat('{', t1.columna, '}\_{blablablah}\_{', t1.columnb,'}')
```